# Вывод массива в richtextbox

Tags: c#, массивы, winforms

У меня есть заполняемый случайными числами массив, который необходимо вывести в richTextBox. Ранее заполнение массива и его вывод я оформлял прямо в коде кнопки "вывести", который выглядел следующим образом:

```
void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    richTextBox1.Clear();
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < L; i++) {
        string s = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            M[i,j] = rand.NextDouble() * (Rend - Rbeg) + Rbeg;
            s = s + string.Format("{0,7:F2}", M[i,j]);
            }
        richTextBox1.AppendText(s + "\n");
    }
}
```

Цикл генерировал новое число в массиве, а затем добавлял его в строку s, в результате чего в строке накапливалось n-ное количество значений, которые потом через ApppendText выводились на экран. В результате получался следующий вид массива:

[image: Вывод массива 1]

Далее я решил перенести заполнение массива в другой модуль Class1, в котором сделал отдельный метод, возвращающий в  итоге массив. Теперь мне необходимо понять, как его можно вывести в таком же виде в AppendText. Единственное, что мне приходит на ум - создать отдельный метод, в котором объявить строковый массив размером с количество строк массива, после чего заполнить его строчками с линиями присоединённых друг к другу значений. **Есть ли возможность осуществить вывод через метод в более удобном и простом виде, без необходимости делать отдельный строковый массив?**

Comment: [StringBuilder](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-5.0)  вам в помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как операция конкатенации строк - медленно, а каждое обращение к интерфейсу в данном случае еще медленнее, можно первое заменить на `StringBuilder`, а второе сделать 1 раз.

```cs
private void PrintArray(double[,] numbers)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < numbers.GetLength(1); j++)
            sb.Append(numbers[i, j].ToString("F2").PadLeft(7)); // можно string.Format, разницы нет
        sb.AppendLine();
    }
    richTextBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
}
```